# Why delete can perform on pointers to const while free cannot?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I've just noticed that the pointers passed to `delete` can be `const` qualified while those passed to `free` cannot. That is really a surprise to me.

And in C++ an overload to `operator delete` should have a signature like:

```
void operator delete(void* p);
```

But adding a `const` to the parameter pointer is invalid:

```
void operator delete(void const* p);
```

May anyone tell me why `delete` is designed this way?

Comment: Please note that a [**const pointer** is different from a **pointer to const**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/pointers/const_pointers.html). I have edited your title in order to correct your terminology.

Comment: As to `free()` (from a C point of view):  https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/1/16/227 .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`free` should not be used with actual C++ objects. `free` should be used with `malloc`, so you shouldn't be using `free` on something you allocated with `new`.

As to why you can `delete` const objects, that's simple:

```
const Type *ptr = new Type(...);
```

Now what? If you couldn't delete that, then you'd have to do this:

```
delete const_cast<Type*>(ptr);
```

Having an object be `const` means that it cannot be modified. You cannot cause the object to go from one state to another state. Deletion is throwing it away. Meaning that it no longer exists in *any* state, whether the original one or some other modified form. Deletion is an operation that exists outside of the object's mutability state, much like construction.

Conceptually, deletion is neither const nor non-const. While a destructor is a non-const function, the idea of destructing an object is simply outside the domain of const or non-const.

---

OK, let's say you define `operator delete` to take a [pointer to const (which is different from a const pointer)](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/pointers/const_pointers.html):

```
void operator delete(void const* p);
```

What is the first line of this function going to be? The purpose of `operator delete` is to free memory that was allocated by `operator new`. That will require poking at bits on the memory allocation heap. And to do that, you need a pointer that does not point to const data:

```
void *ptr = const_cast<void*>(p);
```

[Welcome to *undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast). While C++ allows you to do this, the specification is very clear that the results of attempting to write to `ptr` (or any address based on it) are *undefined*. You were given a const pointer; you were told by the outside world not to modify the stuff it pointed to. C++ provides no guarantees about what happens when you break that contract.

Since the specification states that this is undefined behavior, and since `operator delete` (in most cases) cannot do its job *without* modifying the memory pointed to by `p` (or modifying memory based on that address), it would be silly of the specification to then allow you to define `operator delete` this way. It would basically be canonizing the idea of shooting yourself in the foot.

Yes, in virtually every case, this would be completely safe. But since you're going to cast away the const anyway, why even bother to allow the rather dubious idea in the first place?

Comment: You could even say `const Type *ptr = new const Type(...);` in which case the `const_cast` would be illegal.

Comment: answers only half of the question

Comment: @Jens: What part of the question didn't I answer?

Comment: Would you like to tell me why `operator delete` overloads cannot have the parameter pointer `const` qualified?

Comment: @Nicol, the part about `free`. You just evacuate the question instead of giving an answer. originally the question also was tagged C, but in any case it deserves an answer also from a point of view of C++

Comment: @Jens: I did give an answer from the point of view of C++. In C++, you should not be using `free` on live objects.

Comment: @Nicol, as you said you should only use `free` for objects that are allocated with `malloc`. But the question was not about that, but about the `const`ness of the argument to `free` (and `delete`). You didn't give any clue about that.

Comment: Please note that a [**const pointer** is different from a **pointer to const**](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/pointers/const_pointers.html). Both the question and the answer use incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 7):

`free` is C function. Its signature is 20-30 years old, from times where there were no `const` in C language (and there was no C++ language as well). C++ compiler treats `free` like every other function, and can't let it accept `const` pointer without cast, because `free` could possibly change object pointed. Actually, it does, as well as `delete`, but C++ doesn't know that `free` is used for memory management.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` modifier applied to a pointer means that the object pointed to will not be modified.

However, `delete` takes the object permanently out of circulation. No one need care what happens to it after it is deleted. Hence for all we know, deletion might modify the object or it might not. Why does it matter? Any attempt to read or write the object's contents would be undefined behaviour.

On the other hand, when you're implementing your own `delete`, you will likely need to modify the dying object. Hence the need for the pointer to be non-const.

Comment: answers only half of the question

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that `free` is a library function and you must match the parameter type. When `free` was added to the C language there was no `const` keyword, so that couldn't even be considered.

In C++ `delete p` is a statement handled by the compiler. It can do whatever the language designer wants it to, including not consider if the object pointed to is `const` or not.

Philosophically speaking, the `delete` statement doesn't modify the object, it just makes it go away.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, undefined behavior is predicated **only** on the constness of the object as instantiated, **not** the presence of a const qualifier along an access path thereto.  Thus, const_cast can be used to modify objects behind a pointer of const-qualified target type, so long as the objects were not instantiated const.

Because malloc() instantiates non-const primitive data, it would be completely legal for free() to take a pointer to const, then cast it away and modify the memory as necessary. But because free() predates the const keyword, it does not qualify as it should.

C++ pogrammers may cast away const in order to free malloc'd memory.