# Detect calling delete on stack variables (with cast-to-pointer operator)

Tags: c++

**tldr**

Is there a way, to statically detect error in following code?

```
struct Foo
{
    operator const int*()
    {
        return &data;
    }

    int data;
};

int main() 
{
    Foo f;
    delete f;
}
```

since there is a conversion from Foo to void* containing just one user defined conversion, it is actually allowed to call `delete` on `f`.

**longer story**

in our codebase, there was a really stupid way of deserialize strings, in pseudocode

```
char * buff = bar.loadString();
use buff;
delete buff;
```

the way was changed, to one templated load function, so now deserialize looks like

```
bar.load(m_IntMember);
bar.load(m_StringMember);
```

but all occurrences (there was a lot of them) of `loadString` had to be manually changed like this:

```
string buff;
bar.load(buff);
use buff;
```

we all know what human error can cause, so there are places, where code was wrongly modified like

```
string buff;
bar.load(buff);
use buff;
delete buff;        //notice the delete
```

since we are using a bit non-standard implementation of `string` it actually has a `overloaded const char * operator`, which can be casted to `void*` which can be deleted...

I would like to catch all of these errors at compile time (we have custom high performance allocators, so at runtime, it is easy to corrupt memory without any runtime error)

I cannot declare global delete operator accepting `const char*`
I cannot temporarily delete delete operator from `string` because it is heavily used, so it is unable to compile without it (I cannot "filter out" described error from all errors, because msvc stops compilation when reaching certain amount of errors)

what can I do?

Comment: It's not possible to distinguish. Use a smart pointer rather.

Comment: `const char*` is not implicitly convertible to `void*` since it loses `const`-ness.  It is implicitly convertible to `const void*`, but that shouldn't be a legal argument to `delete`.  Are you explicitly casting somewhere?

Comment: @jamesdlin it compiles fine when I modify example to returns `const int*`  see http://ideone.com/aL23m2

Comment: @relaxxx Ah, I am mistaken about `delete`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965796/why-delete-can-perform-on-pointers-to-const-while-free-cannot That said, the part of your question about "which can be casted to `void*` which can be deleted" is incorrect and not relevant.

Comment: A *delete-expression* (`delete`) doesn't need to convert any pointer to `void*`. (You might be thinking of `operator delete`, which an different thing.)

Comment: With clang tool, you may have AST and found `delete string` or even the consecutive sequence of statements. Require some code though.

Comment: Since you're not actually trying to build a tool for static code analysis, but simply find all occurences of your specific anti pattern, why not use multi-line regex to find them? Consider replacing some variable names with one regex-replace to better distinguish them in later regex searches...

Comment: Why don't you just comment the cast operator in your string class out? If you compile then it should warn you off all occurences it is used at. Including the deletes. You can then again easily detect you problem cases where the compiler warns you. For MSVC this would be some kind of error like `error C2440: 'delete': cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'void*'`. Of course this won't work if the `string` is passed to a function as `const char*` and deleted in there.

Comment: @SimonKraemer because that operator is widely used in code, so commenting it out causes compilation error and certain number of error stops the compilation (as described in question)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() : data(42) {}

    operator const int*()
    {
        return &data;
    }

    int data;

    struct AmbiguousPointerConversion {};
    private: operator AmbiguousPointerConversion *() {
        throw "hi";
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Foo f;
    const int *p = f;
    std::cout << *p << '\n';
    delete f;
}
```

Compiling this with g++ gives me:

```
try.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
try.cc:25:12: error: ambiguous default type conversion from ‘Foo’
     delete f;
            ^
try.cc:25:12: note:   candidate conversions include ‘Foo::operator const int*()’ and ‘Foo::operator Foo::AmbiguousPointerConversion*()’
try.cc:25:12: error: type ‘struct Foo’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
```

Comment: Both conversions probably should be `const`, but absolutely identical. You wouldn't want the intentional ambiguity to be resolved by overloading on `const`.